# How do I get XLS data to appear in CSV form the same way it displays in the file?

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, xls, roo-gem

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 and am using the roo-xls gem.  I parse my .xls file using the following code

```
book = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file_location)
sheet = book.sheet(0)
text = sheet.to_csv
arr_of_arrs = CSV.parse(text)
```

One oddity I’m noticing, is that cells in my XLS file that read as “53:52.56” appear in my CSV data as “0.037413888888888885”.  All the other cells appear in the CSV data the same way they do in the XLS file.  How can I get this one row to show up in my CSV data the same way it appears in the XLS file?

Comment: [`Roo::Base#to_csv`](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/33e20b202d9c6d6c8ec97e132a67059de7ef45c8/lib/roo/base.rb#L695) tries to guess the cell type and occasionally fails. You should read the rows one by one, using `excelx_value(row, col)` or even explicitly specifying the type to be `String`.

Comment: Can you use excelx_value(row, col) even if the file is not an xlsx file (e.g. an xls file)?

Comment: I never dealt with `xls` files, sorry.

Comment: `cell` in `roo-xls` should provide you with the same functionality as `excelx_value` since `excelx_value` is deprecated and simple refers to `cell_value` (`roo` implements `Cell` as a class where as `roo-xls` implements cells in an `Array` of `Hash` Objects)